# Symfony Form Validation not working in Edit

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

Form Validation only works in `new` but not in `edit` even though both use the same Form (error below). Am I using form validation wrong?

- [Entity/Post](https://github.com/rwkt/demo-dynamicform/blob/master/src/Entity/Post.php)
- [Form/PostType](https://github.com/rwkt/demo-dynamicform/blob/master/src/Form/PostType.php)

**Demo repo:** https://github.com/rwkt/demo-dynamicform

1. Create a new post with a title; 2. Edit the post to remove the title and save.

**Error**

Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "title".

[image: exception screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setter requires string,not ?string (string or null). So it is RQUIRED to pass it string (not null). Validation works after populating the object, so it first calls setTitle, then it validates. But since you filled nothing, it calls setTitle(null) and php throws error before validator validates the data.

Refactor your setter to setTitle(?string)

Comment: Thanks, that works; I thought the setter wouldn't be called until after the value has been validated.

Comment: @Rayman since constraints are on object (and not form) - the object needs to be populated and then validated. If you move your constraints to Form, you can leave `setTitle(string)` but you will lose ability to validate your object outside of Form.

Comment: I've done like you said - put the NotBlank constraint in PostType for the title field and removed the Assert in the Post Entity, and have the setter without the `?`. Sadly it's the same error as before. (I've commited to the github repo so you can see what I changed)

Comment: @Rayman Because by default symfony maps empty values to `null`. Set `'empty_data' => ''` in the field options.

Comment: Hello! 
I have the same problem. Did you solve it?